# search and replace html tags (with slashes) in sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file that contains this `<!-- CordovaVersion -->`
I want to replace it with `<script src="cordova-1.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I tried

```
sed 's/"<!-- CordovaVersion -->"/"<script src="cordova-1.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>"/g' junk4 > junk4_modified
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use some other character like *#* as delimiter instead of */*.

```
sed 's#<!-- CordovaVersion -->#<script src="cordova-1.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>#g' junk4 > junk4_modified
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need the extra `"`s as [LiKao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928651/912144) said. Second, you need to know how sed understands what gets replaced with what:

```
s/this/that/flags
```

This means replace `this` with `that` with additional flags (for example `g` means everywhere). In fact the `/` is not a special character, you could use any other such as `#` as [scai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928632/912144) said:

```
s#this#that#flags
```

But what was the problem? Imagine you want to replace `this` with `th/at`. Then sed sees this:

```
s/this/th/at/flags
```

and gets rightly confused. Are you trying to replace `this` with `th`? Than what does `at/flags` mean? Are you trying to replace `this/th` with `at`? Or is it `this` with `th/at`? There is no way to tell.

That is why you should escape the special characters with a `\`. Since we used `/` as delimiter, then we have to escape it when it's not a delimiter:

```
sed 's/<!-- CordovaVersion -->/<script src="cordova-1.7.0.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/g' junk4 > junk4_modified
```

(Of course if we used # and inside `this` or `that` there was a `#` you should have escaped `#`)

You could read [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for more info about sed, including its special characters.

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/<!--\s*CordovaVersion\s*-->/<script src="cordova-1.7.0.js" type="text\/javascript"><\/script>/g' junk4 > junk4_modified`

Answer (score 1):

With this line sed will search for `"<!-- CordovaVersion -->"` and try to replace it with `<script src="cordova-1.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>"`. But your original document does not contain the `"`. Just remove them from the sed command.